# iPhone - ShareKit Facebook Password field is not in secured text entry for second time

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-4.2

Hi i am using **sharekit** API for sharing a text in my iPhone app,i am facing a problem in Facebook login page while sharing if i enter wrong userid and password once and for the next time the **password field is not in secure mode** whatever password i enter it is visible.     can anyone help   thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SHKFormFieldTypePassword is important check this out not SHKFormFieldTypeText

```
    - (NSArray *)authorizationFormFields
    {
        return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [SHKFormFieldSettings label:@"Username"
                                        key:@"username"
                                       type:SHKFormFieldTypeText
                                      start:nil],
                [SHKFormFieldSettings label:@"Password"
                                        key:@"password"
                                       type:SHKFormFieldTypePassword
                                      start:nil],           
                nil];
    }
```